# Order of data in bigquery repeated records

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I know (or control) in what order the records in a repeated field will be returned when using aggregation function?

If for example I'm using "group_concat(children.name) within children" can I assume that the concatenation order will be the same as inserted to the table in the JSON?

Same applies to first(children.name) within children.

Is there a way to sort the data without using ORDER BY on the whole table which is extremely expensive from resources perspective? (I keep getting "Resources exceeded during query execution" when trying to do this).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Order should be preserved among records in a nested or repeated field.

There isn't a way to sort without using order by. If you only need the first few values, you can try using `TOP()` or splitting it up into two queries and doing a `WHERE` clause limitation. E.g. for the first query you find out a split point (perhaps using `QUANTILES()`) the second query you add `WHERE field < split_point`.