# How to sort an array in BigQuery standard SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I am wondering if it is possible to order (apply order by) for individual array values in Google BigQuery?

I am able to achieve this by applying order by on the whole transactonal base table first, then aggregating array; but when table is too large, resource errors appear for ordering by a large table..

So i am wondering if each individual array value can be ordered by using SQL or UDF.

This was asked once [Order of data in bigquery repeated records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155023/order-of-data-in-bigquery-repeated-records) but it was 4,5 years ago.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sure, you can use the ARRAY function. It supports an optional ORDER BY clause. You haven't provided sample data, but supposing that you have a top level array column named `arr`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x ORDER BY x) AS arr
FROM MyTable;
```

This sorts the elements of `arr` by their values.

If you actually have an array of a struct type, such as `ARRAY<STRUCT<a INT64, b STRING>>`, you can sort by one of the struct fields:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ARRAY(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x ORDER BY a) AS arr
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the array is obtained after aggregation using a `group by` clause, the
query can look something like this:

```
SELECT 
ARRAY_AGG(distinct col order by col)
FROM table
GROUP BY group_col
```

So, no `SELECT` is required.

Ref: The accepted answer didn't help. Took help from here - https://count.co/sql-resources/bigquery-standard-sql/array_agg